# loop through chrome tabs and close page depending on web address

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to be able to loop through all the tabs on a chrome page and close any tabs which are youtube pages.

I have done some googling & found the code below. There are two (well probably more) issues. Firstly I have create a WPF application and added the System.Windows.Automation namespace (using visual studio 2015 .net 4.5) but AutomationElement is not recognised.

Also I am unsure of how to loop through the tabs and test if a page is a youtube page.

```
        Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

        if (procsChrome.Length <= 0)
            return null;

        foreach (Process proc in procsChrome)
        {
            // the chrome process must have a window 
            if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                continue;

            // to find the tabs we first need to locate something reliable - the 'New Tab' button 
            AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
            var SearchBar = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
            if (SearchBar != null)
            {
                AutomationPattern[] patterns = SearchBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
                if(patterns.Length > 0)
                {
                    ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)SearchBar.GetCachedPattern(patterns[0]);
                    if (val.Current.Value.Contains("youtube.com") || val.Current.Value.Contains("youtube.co.uk"))
                        proc.Close();
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Have you considered approaching this problem from another direction -- like installing [Domain Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/domain-blocker/ggdcjplapccgoinblmidpkoocfafajfa?hl=en) so that the youtube tabs never get opened in the first place?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling no we actually don't have a problem with youtube tabs being opened. However after a certain time (i.e. people have the left the office) that any youtube tabs are closed

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to make sure that employees that have left for the day aren't chewing up bandwidth by streaming videos?

Comment: yep that is exactly it!

Answer (score 4):

System.Windows.Automation is in UIAutomationClient.dll.Did you add UIAutomationClient.dll as a reference to your project?

Check for value "youtube".

```
if (SearchBar != null) 
{
    AutomationPattern[] patterns = SearchBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
    if (patterns.Length > 0) 
    {
        ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)SearchBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
        if(val.Current.Value.Contains("youtube.com"))
            proc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an InvalidOperationException was unhandled errror. Occurred in UIAutomationClient.dll. Additional information: Unsupported Pattern. It happends at the ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern).SearchBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]); line

Comment: if debug the line return (string)SearchBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(ValuePatternIdentifiers.ValueProperty); it does indeed return the correct web address, i.e. this page

Comment: Then check if that string value contains youtube.com and then close the proc.

Comment: Sorry maybe i wasn't being clear. I have edited my question to show the code that I now have. The error happens on the line ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern).SearchBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);

Comment: @mHelpMe - it means the SearchBar element does not support the ValuePattern. Indeed, from my own research with latest versions of chrome, I don't think it does. The value of the url/adress is not contained in the element, but in another element that's global per chrome window. I don't think you can get this url value without selecting the tab first, which would cause visual flickering

Comment: @SimonMourier I see. The visual flickering would actually be ok in this instance

Comment: @mHelpMe - I've tried various thing but can't find a suitable pattern to use... chrome is notoriously not UI automation-friendly unfortunately. Most people use selenium/webdriver for automating chrome (or FF).

Comment: This line works: ValuePattern val = SearchBar.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;

Answer (score 4):

Based on your question, I wrote a small program to achieve this. Let me know if it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    static void Main()
    {
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

        if (procs.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Google Chrome is not currently open");
            return;
        }

        List<string> titles = new List<string>();

        IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        int id = 0;
        int numTabs = procs.Length;

        foreach (Process p in procs)
        {
            if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
            {
                hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
                id = p.Id;
                break;
            }
        }

        bool isMinimized = IsIconic(hWnd);

        if (isMinimized)
        {
            ShowWindow(hWnd, 9); // restore
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        SendKeys.SendWait("^1"); // change focus to first tab
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        int next = 1;
        string title;

        while (next <= numTabs)
        {
            try
            {
                title = Process.GetProcessById(id).MainWindowTitle.Replace(" - Google Chrome", "");
                if (title.ToLower().Contains("youtube"))
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait("^{w}"); // close tab.
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                next++;
                SendKeys.SendWait("^{TAB}"); // change focus to next tab
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Chrome internal process, doesn't have tab.

            }               
        }

        if (isMinimized)
        {
            ShowWindow(hWnd, 6); // minimize again
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        hWnd = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        Console.WriteLine("Closed youtube tabs");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done easily with AutoHotkey

Here is a script that will open Chrome, loop all tabs and close the YouTube ones, then minimize Chrome again

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

SetTitleMatchMode, 2


IfWinExist, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
{
    WinActivate, Chrome
    WinGetActiveTitle, ActiveWindowOld
    Loop {
        Send, ^{Tab}
        Sleep, 500
        WinGetActiveTitle, ActiveWindow
        if (ActiveWindow = ActiveWindowOld)
        {
            break
        }
        IfInString, ActiveWindow, YouTube - Google Chrome
        {
            Send, ^{w}
        }
    }
    WinMinimize, Chrome
}
```

Credit: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/148742-cycling-through-all-chrome-tabs-and-closing-a-specific-tab/

Answer (score 2):

```
if (SearchBar != null)
{
    bool valuePatternExist = (bool)SearchBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.IsValuePatternAvailableProperty);
    if (valuePatternExist)
    {
        ValuePattern val = SearchBar.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
        if (val.Current.Value.Contains("youtube.com") || val.Current.Value.Contains("youtube.co.uk"))
            proc.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Killing just Chrome tabs with YouTube doesn't really seem like a solution to the actual problem here. I think it would fair easier and more reliable to force all the workstations to go to sleep.

Something from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/463646/is-there-a-command-line-tool-to-put-windows-8-to-sleep/463652#463652) ought to do the trick.
`rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0` perhaps?